# problems with calling server socket accept method with an infinite timeout

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, serversocket

I created a server socket on my side. I don't know when client connects to me.

Calling a serverSocket.accept() in my application without setting any socket timeout would solve my problem of accepting the client at any point of time. I am doing this in a separate thread, so this wouldn't block another part of my application.

My concern is since accept() blocks till it gets a call from a client wouldn't this consume any resources, may be like if I don't get a call from the client side program for about a week.

Is there any other way of accepting the client side connection. I don't have any information on when client calls for a socket connection, except that it calls at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with calling `accept` on a different thread. The thread will be blocked in the call to `accept` and will not be scheduled by the operating system until a connection in inbound. Practically, if you don't get a connection the entire week your thread will not run on the CPU during this time.

Therefore, it will not consume any CPU resources and only a bit of memory.

Comment: or so we hope ;) It depends on the JVM implementation and perhaps OS (for scheduling). I agree with your post Tudor.

Comment: But how will the JVM know there is a connection inbound, may be internally some other thread within the JVM should be constantly hitting the socket to see if there are any inbound connections which might consume resources

Comment: 'But how will the JVM know there is a connection inbound' - because accept() returns. 'may be internally some other thread within the JVM should be constantly hitting the socket to see if there are any inbound connections' - not on any OS I have ever used.  The thread that called accept() is made ready by a signal from a kernel thread running the TCP stack. The kernel threads are, in turn, made ready by signals from the NIC driver and so, originally, from a hardware interrupt.  No polling.  Like @Tudor says - if nothing tries to connect, nothing will be happening.